# How to setup GRPC Ingress on GKE (w/ nginx-ingress)

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, grpc-go

Good Morning. I have a GRPC server that I want to serve on Google Kubernetes Engine. My cluster already has the `nginx-ingress` controller installed, and I'm currently using this to serve http/https traffic. This is the ingress resource I've tried to make to host the GRPC server:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - bar.foo.com
    secretName: reploy-tls
  rules:
  - host: bar.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          serviceName: bar-backend-service
          servicePort: 50051
```

And here's the service/deployment for the app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bar-backend-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: bar-backend-app
  ports:
  - port: 50051
    targetPort: 50051
    name: grpc
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bar-backend
  labels:
    app: bar-backend-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bar-backend-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bar-backend-image
        image: gcr.io/himank-jay/bar-backend-image:TAG
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50051
          name: grpc
```

When I run `grpc_cli ls bar.foo.com:443` (using [grpc_cli](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md)), I get the following error:

```
{"created":"@1580833741.460274000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:x.x.x.x:x","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Socket closed","grpc_status":14}
```

And the error from the `nginx-controller` is as follows:

```
x.x.x.x - - [04/Feb/2020:16:28:46 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.020 [] [] - - - - xxxxx
```

Any ideas on what's wrong here? Or any thoughts on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

The server is serving HTTP/1.x, not HTTP/2 that's required for gRPC.

You can try adding the following annotation to the `Ingress` config

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
```

...as explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/grpc#step-3-the-kubernetes-ingress).

It is also worth checking the `use-http2` flag in the nginx [configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-http2) (it should be enabled, `true`, by default).

---

EDIT, regarding the new error:

`PRI * HTTP/2.0` is the so-called [HTTP/2 Connection Preface](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.3.5) - part of negotiating HTTP/2. It still appears that nginx isn't configured for HTTP/2.

Comment: I've edited my answer above; getting a different error now after fixing a cert issue.

Comment: I added explanation about the `PRI * HTTP/2.0` request erroring out.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck here. Decided on just exposing the set of pods in front of a default `type: LoadBalancer`.

Comment: Still nothing on this @JayK. ? I need Ingress since I need to forward from domain.com to IP (and then I can't specify port)

Comment: @Emixam23 for this particular solution, still no luck. Something I recently came across was this: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#using_grpc_with_your_applications

You can use a standard google cloud load balancer behind your service to forward http2/grpc traffic. I haven't tried this, but it seems like you can set the domain name rules you're looking to get.